# Invalid postback or callback argument when using loadbalancer and webgate

Tags: iis, server, load-balancing

Hi I have developed an asp.net website which is deployed on two server. This site  is working fine when I access the site using IP address of servers in URL like https://123.123.123.12/Pagename.aspx. When I access site using loadbalancer DNS name (https://DNSName/Pagename.aspx) and webgate some of the pages are throwing following exceptions

"Invalid postback or callback argument" or "The serialized data is invalid."

This is happending intermittently. That is same page, some time shows correct data and sometimes throws exception.

When I stopped website(IIS) on one of the server all pages works as excepted without throwing above exceptions.

I also verified machine keys on both servers, machine key value is same on both servers. There others websites on the same servers which are working fine with loadbalancer DNS URL (//DNSName/Pagename.aspx) and webgate.

Can someone help me with this?

Below is the StackTrace

```
<Description>An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred and was caught.</Description>
  <ExceptionType>System.ArgumentException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
  <Message>Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using &lt;pages enableEventValidation="true"/&gt; in configuration or &lt;%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %&gt; in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.</Message>
  <Source>System.Web</Source>
  <HelpLink />
  <Property name="ParamName">&lt;undefined value&gt;</Property>
  <Property name="Data">System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal</Property>
  <Property name="TargetSite">Void ValidateEvent(System.String, System.String)</Property>
  <Property name="HResult">-2147024809</Property>
  <StackTrace>   at System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent(String uniqueId, String argument)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData, Boolean fBeforeLoad)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)</StackTrace>
```

Comment: Welcome! Please post entire stack traces/error messages from the logs, that makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research I figured out that both servers doesn't have windows updates(may be missing some patches). After performing windows updates on both machines my site started working fine even with load balancer DNS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this caused us a big headache.
Bottom line is in IIS web farms, keep all the servers exactly alike, the OS patches, especially the .net framework. For the .net framework, check using regedit, since IIS app pool reported it incorrectly.
If they are not all the same ( including OS patches ), be prepared for such headaches with session management.